# Creating riak nodes: bitcask version clash

Tags: fedora, riak

I have installed riak on a Fedora 17 system (but not using the package manager) by following the [standard instructions](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/fast-track/Building-a-Development-Environment/#Build-Riak), i.e.:

```
$ wget http://downloads.basho.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/riak/1.2/1.2.1/riak-1.2.1.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf riak-1.2.1.tar.gz
$ cd riak-1.2.1
$ make all
```

This worked and I now tried to create four nodes as described in the [Fast Track tutorial](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/fast-track/Building-a-Development-Environment/#Use-Rebar-to-Start-Up-Four-Nodes):

```
$ make devrel
```

This runs for a while and then produces the error below:

```
==> rel (generate)
ERROR: generate failed while processing /space/surechem/riak-1.2.1/rel: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,"bitcask: Application version clash. Multiple directories contains version \"1.5.2\"."}},
     [{rebar_reltool,generate,2,[]},
      {rebar_core,run_modules,4,[]},
      {rebar_core,execute,4,[]},
      {rebar_core,process_dir,4,[]},
      {rebar_core,process_commands,2,[]},
      {rebar,main,1,[]},
      {escript,run,2,[{file,"escript.erl"},{line,741}]},
      {escript,start,1,[{file,"escript.erl"},{line,277}]}]}}
make: *** [dev1] Error 1
```

I have difficulties understanding what that error message is trying to tell me.

Is this a version conflict with bitcask? The Fedora package `erlang-bitcask` is installed on the machine (erlang-bitcask-1.5.2-1.fc17.x86_64). Should it be removed? Do I need a different version of it?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this seems to be caused by conflicts with Erlang packages installed in the system. After removing the `erlang-bitcask` package from the system, I got similar error messages for other packages. In the end I had to remove four packages,

```
$ sudo yum remove erlang-bitcask erlang-ebloom erlang-js erlang-luke
```

to get it to work.